# Como restringir acesso a API Java utilizando Spring Security?

Tags: java, api, spring, back-end

Ola.

Eu tenho uma API no meu back-end que fornece os dados para minha aplicação Web (aplicação de consulta de anúncios de imóves).

A aplicação não tem login e senha, tão pouco usuários cadastrados. É uma aplicação onde os usuarios apenas fazem consultas.

Mas queria restringir o acesso diretamente na API, onde só minha aplicação teria este acesso, ou seja restringir acesso a API por terceiros que por ventura queiram utilizar minha API por algum motivo..

Qual seria a melhor solução? A API é desenvolvida em Java Scpring Security.

Comment: Pesquise por autenticação via oAuth. Ela envolve o uso de um token na requisição à sua api. O spring security é totalmente compatível com essa solução.

Comment: Entendo que oAuth limita a requisição com uso de token, mas se eu armazeno esse token em meu JavaScript no cliente, qualquer pessoa irá ver o Token nesse cliente e poderá usa-lo em uma outra aplicação se assim a pessoa desejar.

Comment: Você tem controle sobre o tempo de vida do token. Mesmo que alguém tivesse acesso a ele, possivelmente ele estaria já inválido quando fosse utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de várias maneiras, vou alguns exemplos.

1. Restrinja por IP, apenas os IPs que você definir poderão acessar a API, o que for diferente, você rejeita.
2. Você poderá utilizar o oauth2 também, conforme bem colococou o StatelessDev no comentário acima.